# Styled components and SSR server side rendering and createGlobalStyle

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, server-side-rendering

In the `styled-components` DOCs we get that:

> **Server Side Rendering v2+**
>
> styled-components supports concurrent server side rendering, with stylesheet rehydration. The basic idea is that everytime you render your app on the server, you can create a ServerStyleSheet and add a provider to your React tree, that accepts styles via a context API.
>
> **This doesn't interfere** with global styles, such as keyframes or **createGlobalStyle** and allows you to use styled-components with React DOM's various SSR APIs.

What does it mean by "it doesn't interfere with createGlobalStyle" ?

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  ${resetCSS}
  ${baseCSS}
`;

const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();

const body = renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(
  <Router>
    <GlobalStyle/>
    <Header/>
    <Main/>
    <Footer/>
  </Router>
));
```

**Question**

Will the global styles created with `createGlobalStyle` and inserted with `<GlobalStyle/>` be collected by the `sheet.collectStyles()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the global styles created with `createGlobalStyle` and inserted with `<GlobalStyle/>` be collected by the `sheet.collectStyles()` method?

**Yes!**

**WARNING:** The CSS from `<GlobalStyle/>` might be inserted after other chunks of CSS so things like `@font-face` might break.

So far I only had problems with `@font-face`.